# Sensitivity and Specificity

Tags: probability

True or False: If a screening test has 90% sensitivity and 80% specificity, then 90% of people with disease will test positive.

I know that Sensitivity means that the test is positive for people with the disease, and Specificity means the test is negative for people without the disease. But not sure how to proceed.

Comment: If I understand your definitions correctly, x% sensitivity means *by definition* that x% of people with disease will test positive (which means there is no calculation to be done). In pretty much any other way you could define things, you'll need to use Bayes' rule.

Comment: Right- I'm a beginner and I'm not sure if I have to use Bayes equation or if it's just as easy as saying True.  And thank you!

Comment: You should just carefully check your precise definition of sensitivity and specificity.

Comment: Yes, the definition of sensitivity is the measure of true positives.